# How to solve "Unresolved defparam reference" Error in ModelSIM?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, quartus

I've generated a reciprocal ROM using Quartus II and I've developed a circuit that calculates the hyperbolic tangent. I'm facing the following error when I try to simulate a testbench of my circuit. Note that I've used the ROM as an instantiate in my circuit.

```
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.address_aclr_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.clock_enable_input_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.clock_enable_output_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.init_file.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.intended_device_family.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.lpm_hint.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.lpm_type.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.numwords_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.operation_mode.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.outdata_aclr_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.outdata_reg_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.widthad_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.width_a.
Unresolved defparam reference to 'altsyncram_component' in altsyncram_component.width_byteena_a.
```

and this is the Verilog output of the ROM that I've generated in Quartus II:

```
// megafunction wizard: %ROM: 1-PORT%
// GENERATION: STANDARD
// VERSION: WM1.0
// MODULE: altsyncram 

// ============================================================
// File Name: RecipROM.v
// Megafunction Name(s):
//          altsyncram
//
// Simulation Library Files(s):
//          altera_mf
// ============================================================
// ************************************************************
// THIS IS A WIZARD-GENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!
//
// 12.1 Build 177 11/07/2012 SJ Web Edition
// ************************************************************

    
//Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Altera Corporation
//Your use of Altera Corporation's design tools, logic functions 
//and other software and tools, and its AMPP partner logic 
//functions, and any output files from any of the foregoing 
//(including device programming or simulation files), and any 
//associated documentation or information are expressly subject 
//to the terms and conditions of the Altera Program License 
//Subscription Agreement, Altera MegaCore Function License 
//Agreement, or other applicable license agreement, including, 
//without limitation, that your use is for the sole purpose of 
//programming logic devices manufactured by Altera and sold by 
//Altera or its authorized distributors.  Please refer to the 
//applicable agreement for further details.


// synopsys translate_off
`timescale 1 ps / 1 ps
// synopsys translate_on
module RecipROM (
    address,
    clock,
    q);

    input   [2:0]  address;
    input     clock;
    output  [15:0]  q;
`ifndef ALTERA_RESERVED_QIS
// synopsys translate_off
`endif
    tri1      clock;
`ifndef ALTERA_RESERVED_QIS
// synopsys translate_on
`endif

    wire [15:0] sub_wire0;
    wire [15:0] q = sub_wire0[15:0];

    altsyncram  altsyncram_component (
                .address_a (address),
                .clock0 (clock),
                .q_a (sub_wire0),
                .aclr0 (1'b0),
                .aclr1 (1'b0),
                .address_b (1'b1),
                .addressstall_a (1'b0),
                .addressstall_b (1'b0),
                .byteena_a (1'b1),
                .byteena_b (1'b1),
                .clock1 (1'b1),
                .clocken0 (1'b1),
                .clocken1 (1'b1),
                .clocken2 (1'b1),
                .clocken3 (1'b1),
                .data_a ({16{1'b1}}),
                .data_b (1'b1),
                .eccstatus (),
                .q_b (),
                .rden_a (1'b1),
                .rden_b (1'b1),
                .wren_a (1'b0),
                .wren_b (1'b0));
    defparam
        altsyncram_component.address_aclr_a = "NONE",
        altsyncram_component.clock_enable_input_a = "BYPASS",
        altsyncram_component.clock_enable_output_a = "BYPASS",
        altsyncram_component.init_file = "../initROM.mif",
        altsyncram_component.intended_device_family = "Cyclone IV GX",
        altsyncram_component.lpm_hint = "ENABLE_RUNTIME_MOD=NO",
        altsyncram_component.lpm_type = "altsyncram",
        altsyncram_component.numwords_a = 8,
        altsyncram_component.operation_mode = "ROM",
        altsyncram_component.outdata_aclr_a = "NONE",
        altsyncram_component.outdata_reg_a = "CLOCK0",
        altsyncram_component.widthad_a = 3,
        altsyncram_component.width_a = 16,
        altsyncram_component.width_byteena_a = 1;


endmodule

// ============================================================
// CNX file retrieval info
// ============================================================
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: ADDRESSSTALL_A NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: AclrAddr NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: AclrByte NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: AclrOutput NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: BYTE_ENABLE NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: BYTE_SIZE NUMERIC "8"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: BlankMemory NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: CLOCK_ENABLE_INPUT_A NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: CLOCK_ENABLE_OUTPUT_A NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: Clken NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: IMPLEMENT_IN_LES NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: INIT_FILE_LAYOUT STRING "PORT_A"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: INIT_TO_SIM_X NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: INTENDED_DEVICE_FAMILY STRING "Cyclone IV GX"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: JTAG_ENABLED NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: JTAG_ID STRING "NONE"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: MAXIMUM_DEPTH NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: MIFfilename STRING "../initROM.mif"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: NUMWORDS_A NUMERIC "8"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: RAM_BLOCK_TYPE NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: RegAddr NUMERIC "1"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: RegOutput NUMERIC "1"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: SYNTH_WRAPPER_GEN_POSTFIX STRING "1"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: SingleClock NUMERIC "1"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: UseDQRAM NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: WidthAddr NUMERIC "3"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: WidthData NUMERIC "16"
// Retrieval info: PRIVATE: rden NUMERIC "0"
// Retrieval info: LIBRARY: altera_mf altera_mf.altera_mf_components.all
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: ADDRESS_ACLR_A STRING "NONE"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: CLOCK_ENABLE_INPUT_A STRING "BYPASS"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: CLOCK_ENABLE_OUTPUT_A STRING "BYPASS"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: INIT_FILE STRING "../initROM.mif"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: INTENDED_DEVICE_FAMILY STRING "Cyclone IV GX"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: LPM_HINT STRING "ENABLE_RUNTIME_MOD=NO"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: LPM_TYPE STRING "altsyncram"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: NUMWORDS_A NUMERIC "8"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: OPERATION_MODE STRING "ROM"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: OUTDATA_ACLR_A STRING "NONE"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: OUTDATA_REG_A STRING "CLOCK0"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: WIDTHAD_A NUMERIC "3"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: WIDTH_A NUMERIC "16"
// Retrieval info: CONSTANT: WIDTH_BYTEENA_A NUMERIC "1"
// Retrieval info: USED_PORT: address 0 0 3 0 INPUT NODEFVAL "address[2..0]"
// Retrieval info: USED_PORT: clock 0 0 0 0 INPUT VCC "clock"
// Retrieval info: USED_PORT: q 0 0 16 0 OUTPUT NODEFVAL "q[15..0]"
// Retrieval info: CONNECT: @address_a 0 0 3 0 address 0 0 3 0
// Retrieval info: CONNECT: @clock0 0 0 0 0 clock 0 0 0 0
// Retrieval info: CONNECT: q 0 0 16 0 @q_a 0 0 16 0
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM.v TRUE
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM.inc TRUE
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM.cmp TRUE
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM.bsf TRUE
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM_inst.v TRUE
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM_bb.v TRUE
// Retrieval info: GEN_FILE: TYPE_NORMAL RecipROM_syn.v TRUE
// Retrieval info: LIB_FILE: altera_mf
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Is the Quartus IP module included in the testbench sources? Both the RecipROM and altsyncram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you just need to load the Altera libraries in Modelsim:

- using GUI: `Simulate > Start Simulation > Libraries > Add > altera_mf_ver`
- using console: add `-L altera_mf_ver` to your command.